# Facebook Chatbot delete messages by id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, messenger, dialogflow-es

does anybody know if it is possible to delete messages by id.

For example I have an update for my content so that the user must not see any outdated messages. Didn't find anything in the graph API...

[Message docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/message/)

thx

franzus

Comment: No that is not possible

Answer (score 3):

**Facebook does not allow you to delete messages using the Messenger API, or the Graph API**

I am not aware or, nor have found documentation for, a method that does DELETE operations (or UPDATE for that matter) on a FB Message.

[The Messenger Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform) provide methods for sending messsages, subscribing a page to your application's webhook, retrieving user profile information, and setting various options for your bot.

Comment: can you please link a source?

Comment: FBM docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform No available methods to do anything but send messages and query the graph api, user profile, and set options for your bot